# Applying CSS and element when the checked radio button after it is checked (live)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to apply CSS to the element next to a radio button, but nothing happens:

```
 $('.ordering-options input[type="radio"]').live("change", function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]:checked').next().css('color', 'red');
  });
```

(I also want the default checked radio button to have the CSS applied before any action)

Any suggestions in order to accomplish this?

EDIT: The CSS is applied and disappears in a  second.

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="ordering-options">
    <h2 class="ordering-method">Ordering method:</h2>

    <ul>
      <li><input type="radio" name="take-out" value="false" checked="checked" class=
      "takeout-select" /><span>Take Out</span></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li><input type="radio" name="delivery" value="true" class=
      "delivery-select" /><span>Delivery</span></li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
```

('Take out' is red by default. If the user clicks 'Delivery', the span after it will turn red and vice versa).

Comment: You have tried changing the event handling code to just display a simple alert? My guess is a mis-spelled class name on the first line assuming the missing $ is just a typo).

Comment: @charlieg Thanks. The CSS is applied and disappears in a second.

Comment: $.live() has been deprecated, try using $.on() [http://api.jquery.com/on/]

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a bit more code/context to help debug this issue? It works fine in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n7Sae/

Comment: @charlieg Now it doesn't work on click nor change events.

Comment: I don't follow, sorry. @ChristianVarga pointed to a jsfiddle that works even if you change `live` to `on`

Comment: @Christian Varga OK Please see my EDIT.

Comment: It still works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/n7Sae/1/. But I've re-read the question, and to be honest I don't understand what you actually want to do. Can you please describe exactly what you want to happen - eg, should there only be ONE red field on the form at any time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sold on that HTML structure, but if you'd like to stick with it you could use the following: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TdxNy/15/)

```
function colorRadio(){
    $('.ordering-options input[type="radio"]').closest('li').find('span').css('color', 'black');
    $('.ordering-options input[type="radio"]:checked').closest('li').find('span').css('color', 'red');
}
colorRadio()
$('.ordering-options input[type="radio"]').on("change", colorRadio);
```

It's a function that first resets all the labels to 'black', then changes the checked ones to 'red'. You run it once on page-load, then once for every change of a radio button.

PS: if you want "radio" buttons they have to have the same "name" or they aren't linked